# UK Visa site problems( visa sub type not showing)

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am filling online application for UK visa and the following issue is coming. As you can see in the picture visa subtype category is not showing. Because it is not creating the application. Please share how to solve this issue. I applied for work visa. There is a new visa link but that is for a visit I think. Thanks

Comment: The picture to which you refer is not visible in your post.

Comment: i have the same problem
I can't select the visa sub type like you can see in the picture
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UJ5O.png)

Answer (score 2):

for most visa types, including Visit visa (Tourism, Business, Family Visit, and many others), the website you've accessed is no longer accommodating it.

Instead, you can apply through the new UK Visa online application form on the link below :

https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/alt-language-selection-skip-visa

This new form is a lot simpler and has better user experience imho.

Good luck!